# Refactor two similar Laravel controllers

Tags: php, laravel, controller, refactoring

I've got two controllers. They both do the same thing, the only parameter that differs is $service at the __invoke function.

So, here's my first AcceptFeedbackController.php:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Models\Feedback;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\ModelNotFoundException;

use App\Http\Services\AcceptFeedback;

class AcceptFeedbackController extends Controller
{
    public function __invoke($feedbackId, AcceptFeedback $service)
    {
        try {
            $feedback = Feedback::findOrFail($feedbackId);

            if($service->execute($feedback))
                return redirect(route('task.page', ['id' => $feedback->task->id]));
            else return back();
        }
        catch(ModelNotFoundException $exception) {
            return back();
        }
    }
}
```

Here's the second DeleteFeedbackController.php:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Models\Feedback;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\ModelNotFoundException;

use App\Http\Services\DeleteFeedback;

class DeleteFeedbackController extends Controller
{
    public function __invoke($feedbackId, DeleteFeedback $service)
    {
        try {
            $feedback = Feedback::findOrFail($feedbackId);

            if($service->execute($feedback))
                return redirect(route('task.page', ['id' => $feedback->task->id]));
            else return back();
        }
        catch(ModelNotFoundException $exception) {
            return back();
        }
    }
}
```

My try was to create a single FeedbackController, where I pass the Service class as $service parameter:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Models\Feedback;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\ModelNotFoundException;

use App\Http\Services\AcceptFeedback;
use App\Http\Services\DeleteFeedback;

class FeedbackController extends Controller
{
     public function __invoke($feedbackId, $service)
     {
         try {
             $feedback = Feedback::findOrFail($feedbackId);

             if($service->execute($feedbackId))
                 return redirect(route('task.page', ['id' => $feedback->task->id]));
             else return back();
         }
         catch(ModelNotFoundException $exception) {
             return back();
         }
     }

     public function accept($feedbackId) {
        $this->__invoke($feedbackId, AcceptFeedback::class);
     }

     public function delete($feedbackId) {
        $this->__invoke($feedbackId, DeleteFeedback::class);
     }
 }
```

But I got the following error:

> App\Http\Controllers\FeedbackController::__invoke(): Argument #2 ($service) must be of type App\Http\Services, string given, called in C:\OpenServer\domains\TaskForce\app\Http\Controllers\FeedbackController.php on line 29

What I understood from this is that Laravel expects a **Service class**, but I passed the **string**. How is this even possible, if I pass the whole class there? Is there something I'm doing wrong? Or, maybe there is a better way of refactoring two similar controllers?

Comment: how about passing all data in an associative array in first argument

Comment: AcceptFeedback::class will return the class name instead you should do `new AcceptFeedback()`

Answer (score 0):

Here you are a posible solution

```
<?php

interface FeedBackInterface
{
    public function handle();
}
```

Two concrete clasess for feedback that implements that interface

```
class AcceptFeedback implements FeedBackInterface
{

    public function handle()
    {
        try {
            $feedback = Feedback::findOrFail($feedbackId);
            // Your logic to add feedback
        }
        catch(ModelNotFoundException $exception) {
            return back();
        }
    }
}
```

```
class DeleteFeedback implements FeedBackInterface
{

    public function handle()
    {
        try {
            $feedback = Feedback::findOrFail($feedbackId);
            // Your logic to delete feedback

        }
        catch(ModelNotFoundException $exception) {
            return back();
        }
    }
}
```

And an unique feedback controller

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

class FeedbackController extends Controller
{
    protected FeedBackInterface $feedbackAction;

    public function __construct(FeedBackInterface $feedbackAction)
    {
        $this->$feedbackAction = $feedbackAction;
    }

    public function __invoke()
    {
        return $this->feedbackAction->handle();
    }
}
```

Now when you call your controller only need a Feedback Object that implements the interface.